# Linux Shell Script: how call a method and do the evaluation of the returned value within an if statement at the same time

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

About Linux Shell Script having the following:

```
verifyIfFileExists(){
   ...
   returns 0 # if the file exists
   ...
   returns 1 # if the does not exist 
}

...

something(){

   verifyIfFileExists
   resultVerification=$?

   if [[ $resultVerification -eq 0 ]]; then
      ...   
   else
      ...
   fi
   ...
}
```

The code shown above works as expected. I want to know if is possible and how do the method call and the evaluation within the `if` statement - it to avoid the `resultVerification=$?` declaration - something like:

```
something(){

   verifyIfFileExists

   if [[ $(verifyIfFileExists) -eq 0 ]]; then
      ...   
   else
      ...
   fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if command
```

succeeds if *`command`* exits with a 0 status; in your case,

```
if verifyIfFileExists; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

`[` and `[[` are themselves commands which return 0 or 1 depending on the result of evaluating the expressions given as arguments. So

```
if [[ ...
```

is an instance of the generic

```
if command
```

shown above.

Storing an exit status in a different variable can be useful if you want to use it later; for example

```
... run a command
result=$?
printf "Command foo exited with result %s.\n" "$result"
if [[ "$result" -eq 0 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

If you don’t need that, then

```
command
if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
```

can be rewritten as

```
if command; then
```

which I find simpler to read. This is especially true if your functions are named accordingly, *e.g.*

```
if fileExists; then
```

See also [shellcheck’s SC2181](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181) which lists more pitfalls.

Comment: The command could return either 0 or 1 - and I need explicitly use `-eq` with `0` or `1`

Comment: Actually, those `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]` always sound very silly to me, that's running a `[[...]]` command that returns true if the previous command returned true. Why not doing `cmd; [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; (exit "$?"); (( $? == 0 )); (( ! $? )); if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]...` while we're at running commands that carry on the exit status of the previous command.

Comment: Also, the `verifyIfFileExists` function should probably just be `verifyIfFileExists() [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]]` with no need to call `return` explicitly.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the purpose is have a better readability - exists many if/else blocks, so have many `resultVerification=$?` makes verbose the code.

Comment: @StephenKitt pls consider to add a special note about why `[[ ]]` are not used

Comment: @ManuelJordan, to me those `[ "$?" -eq 0 ]` just betray the fact that the author doesn't know how shell constructs work.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I saw many tutorials and some posts through StackOverflow using  the `if [[ $resultVerification -eq 0 ]]; then` approach

Comment: @ManuelJordan unfortunately many tutorials are written by people who don’t know this sort of thing.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Saving previous exit status in a variable makes sense if you're not using it straight away like in: `cmd; ret=$?; other-cmd; if [ "$ret" -eq 0 ]` (or `if (( ret == 0 ))`...) or if you need to use it several time, like `cmd; ret=$?; if (( ret == 0 )); ...; fi; return "$ret"`...

Comment: @StephenKitt valuable the update of your answer. Well done! - I work how the `... run a command` block, but calling other functions than calling the command directly, it to reuse code and logic through methods

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
  if verifyIfFileExists ; then
     # checking for return code 0
```

or

```
  if ! verifyIfFileExists ; then
         # checking for return code 1
```

Comment: pls consider to add a special note about why `[[ ]]` are not used

Comment: The builtin ```if``` doesn't require ```[[  ]]```, where you have to evaluate an expression. The syntax for ```if _commands_ ; then …``` is very simple, it just uses the return code of _commands_.

Comment: (I think the square brackets are only used so often because many shell scripts have been copy and pasted from older shell scripts for decades.)

Comment: @Erich Regarding your last comment, it's called "[cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)".